# The lists are not passing to main class

Tags: python, list, function, class

sorry, I am new to Python and I understand that the answer should be obvious. I have a class organized with parametrs and constructer, but I can't call any method from that class in main. I guess, it's probably smth with lists-passing.

```
class PersonData:
def __init__(self,nameSet=[],hoursNeed=[],daysOff=[]):
    self.__nameSet=nameSet
    self.__hoursNeed=hoursNeed
    self.__daysOff=daysOff

    def getNameSet(self):
        return self.nameSet

    def setHoursNeed(self,hoursNeed):
        self.hoursNeed=hoursNeed

    def setDaysOff(self,daysOff):
        self.daysOff=daysOff

    def RandomFulfil(nameSet):  #JUST FOR CHECK
        for element in nameSet:
            print(element)
```

The main is here:

```
from PersonData import PersonData
def main():
nameList=[]
hoursList=[]
daysOffList=[]


print("How many employees you have: ")
N=int(input())
for x in range(N):
    print("Enter employees names now: ",N," left: ")
    x=input("")
    nameList.append(x)
    print("Enter employees working hours per week now:")
    y=input("")
    hoursList.append(y)
    print("Enter employees days off per week now:")
    z=input("")
    daysOffList.append(z)
    N-=1

people=PersonData(nameList,hoursList,daysOffList)
#people.any method    <---- this one is not working
```

EDIT:
Now I changed them form being private and I can access to the fields, but still don't have to the methods.

```
    def __init__(self,nameSet,hoursNeed,daysOff):
    self.nameSet=nameSet
    self.hoursNeed=hoursNeed
    self.daysOff=daysOff
```

Comment: Quite a number of things are not quite right with your code. 1. You're using a mutable container as default argument 2. You have some of your instance variables mangled (which I'm not sure is what you intend), and 3. You're accessing non-existent attributes in those methods.

Comment: pls can check my update

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an `AttributeError` when using any of the methods because the variables they are trying to access simply don't exist:

The members you are initializing in the contructor are completely different ones than those you are trying to use in the other methods: `self.__nameSet` is not the same than `self.nameSet`, `self.__daysOff` is not the same than `self.daysOff`, etc.

Also, you shouldn't use a mutable contrainer as a default argument (don't use `nameSet=[]`, etc. in the constructor).

Comment: Also, I don't know how to show in constractor that I will be using nameSet and HourSet as a List.

Comment: @VladDemyan You can check if the given type is list via `isinstance(given_argument, list)` before assigning. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).

Comment: @VladDemyan ok I checked your updated and, again, what do you mean when you say "you don't have the methods"? If you don't describe your problem properly we can't help.

Comment: I mean that in main whe I try to call for example getNameSet, the people.getNameSet() is not seen. I mean that I can access fields, but can't access methods.

Comment: what does "is not seen" mean? Are you getting any error at all? What happens when you do `people.getNameSet()`?

Comment: I mean I can't see it method at all in my main. It sees my variables from other class, but doesn't see any method at all.

Comment: you are not making any sense, I have asked you three times. "I can't see it" does not mean anything. Either say what actual error you are experiencing or we are done trying to help out because what you say is not descriptive at all. I am going to ask one last time: **what output do you see when you execute your actual code?**